# Comparing null data through if statement

Tags: php, html, if-statement, null

I am having trouble comparing a set variable to null. My code runs as

```
.......some code
echo "Question1 is" . $q1. "is Question-1";
?>

<html>
<head>  
<form method="post" method="post" action="jobprocess.php">
<?
    if($q1!="")
    { ?>
        <h3> Answer the below simple questions related to the job and apply </h3>
        <div align="center">
        <input type="text" name="q1" required placeholder="<?php echo $q1;?>"><br>
    <? } ..... some more code
```

The result is shown as

> Question1 isis Question-1
>
> Answer the below simple questions related to the job and apply
>
> [Text Box]

While the first line confirms that variable q1 ="", I cannot understand why is it entering !$q1="" loop

Thank you for your patience
I have gone through the usages of ===null and empty($var) before I have posted this and I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my code

Comment: Update: I have tried setting default value in sql table as 0 and comparing to 0, still it enters the loop. I sense a logical error than a syntax error

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($q1);`

Comment: To see the real value of a variable use `var_dump`.

Comment: @u_mulder kinshuk vardump shows null

Comment: @u_mulder based on the link you shared, i tried using is_null($q1) but it did not help either

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy what is the value for is_null($q1) ?

Comment: @AyaSalama This is strange: 
is_null($q1) returns 1. 
When I user if(is_null($q1)!=1), it still enters the loop. 
Strangely, even if(is_null($q1)=0 enters the loop

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy try if(!is_null($q1))

Comment: try to use this code `if(!is_null($q1) && strlen($q1)> 0)`

Comment: @dass I tried if(!is_null($q1) && strlen($q1)>0) and it showed 0) { ?> before 'answer the..... ' 
I tried if(!is_null($q1) && strlen($q1)!=0) and it still entered the loop

Comment: is that $q1 value from database??

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy `if(isset($q1) && strlen($q1) > 0)` try this one.. i used this code and it works fine for me

Comment: @dass.. No the value of $q1 in database in null

Comment: have you try the last code i commented just now..?

Comment: @dass... does not work for me.
I want to prevent the code from entering the loop when $q1=null, it enters the loop everytime

Comment: what if you fetch the rows which are $q1 not null?? is that possible

Comment: are you using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`??

Comment: @dass... I am using mysql_fetch_assoc() 
Any pointers ?

Comment: can i see your full code??

Comment: @dass... Thank you it just got resolved. The code is live at www.zigsaw.in/jobs 
When you apply for a job you will be redirected to a apply2.php page where the code is
I used is_null($q1) as suggested by Aya Salama with some modifications. 
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `if(!is_null($q1))` instead of your condition